# How to use decrypt function via OpenJPA with a PostgreSQL backend?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, encryption, openjpa

I am using `encrypt` function on a PostgreSQL database enhanced with [pgcrypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html). Both encrypt and decrypt functions have three parameters: `(Value, Key, Encryption Standard)`.

Now I have to get the information and execute `decrypt` function in a transparent manner from within **OpenJPA**. How can this be achieved?

Comment: have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897558/how-to-use-jpa-to-query-encrypted-data ?

Comment: Yes, but no solution was given, just suggests to use Java encryptation, and I need that on JPA side.

Comment: JPA is "in Java" as it is an object-relational mapper specification and is implemented for instance by OpenJPA in: Java. What you really mean is: at DB level already?

Comment: Yes, I need to use the decrypt function of postgre with the same key I used on encrypt, and I want to know how can I do that with OpenJPA.